# How do I get eclipse to edit *build.xml as an ant build file

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am running eclipse Indigo.
I have some build files that are NOT named build.xml
How do I update the eclipse config so that eclipse will treat these as ant build files.

I have looked at Preferences-> General -> Content Types -> Text -> XML-> Ant Buildfile
And I tried to add *build.xml, but I had an error

> The file name cannot include the wild card character (*) in the current location

Used to be when I looked at the Outline view of the build.xml I had a nice hierarchy (File was recognized as Ant Build). That is no longer working. Now I get "An outline is not available". The most recent change was downloading all of oracle's plugins so I could run a local app server.

Right clicking on the file to explicitly choose Ant editor works. (Thanks Alex)

Any suggestions on how to get eclipse to recognize these files as build files instead of standard xml files? I miss the single click opening.

Comment: Eclipse should be able to detect an Ant build file just by its content, not just by its file name. I have a bunch of common-buid-*.xml and Eclipse open then with the Ant editor.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on your `*build.xml` in Package Explorer, and selecting Open With -> Ant Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, you cannot associate complex filenames with editors (there's a bug opened for this functionality but has not been implemented thus far, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=89859).

You can only associate complete filenames (like `build.xml`) or simple wildcards like `*.xml`.

An easy way to work around this is using a special extension for your ant files (Eclipse already comes pre-configured with support for `*.ant` or `*.ent` files). So the simplest way is renaming your build scripts to use `.ant` as extension. Depending on your situation, this can be a solution.

If you cannot renames files for whatever reason, then the only solution is to associate each file individually to the ANT editor. You can do this, as suggested, by right-clicking the file and choosing `Open With -> Ant Editor`. Eclipse will remember your choice the next time you open the same file.